# Is there a way to set a $_SESSION variable from a table which is created with a loop

Tags: php, sql, pdo, session-variables

Im am working on a school project and we need to make a website using a database and what Im trying to create now is a FAQ forum for our school and all I need is a way to awnser the questions. Right now I have a table with questions generated using this code.

`

```
  $query="SELECT vraag, vragen_id, v_naam, tv, a_naam
          FROM vragen, personen
          WHERE vak_id = 1
          AND vragen.id=personen.id
          GROUP BY vraag
          ORDER BY vragen_id DESC";
  $result=$conn->query($query);

  echo "<table class = 'w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-hoverable'>";
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Vraag nummer &nbsp</th>";
        echo "<th>Gestelde vraag &nbsp</th>";
        echo "<th>Gesteld door &nbsp</th>";
      echo "</tr>";

    foreach($result as $row) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['vragen_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='antwoorden.php'>" . $row['vraag'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['v_naam'] . " " . $row['tv'] . " " .  $row['a_naam'] ."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";
?>`
```

And I need to know if there is a way for me to set `$_SESSION['vraag']` to the value of the `$row['vraag']` which has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass the value of `$row['vraag']` when the user clicks on it.

```
echo "<td><a href='antwoorden.php?vraag=".$row['vraag']."'>" . $row['vraag'] . "</a></td>";
```

and then read it in the code of `antwoorden.php` and write it to the session

```
// do not forget to activate session
session_start();

$_SESSION['vraag'] = $_GET['vraag'];
```

Comment: I tried using this code and when clicking on the question I got and error saying I didn't have permission to acces the folder. And when removing the middle ```>``` in ```<a href='antwoorden.php>?vraag=".$row['vraag']."'>``` it sent me back to the previous page.

Comment: I figured it out because I had some code from a previous attempt still running which was checking to see if ``` $_SESSION['vraag']``` was empty and that was causing me to go back to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to store the answers in the database

Because your questions will contain spaces an other characters that you have to create a identifier for the row a get will get you in trouble. I think it's easier to use a post request for this.

an option is to create an answer form for each row:

```
<form action="/antwoorden.php" method="post">
   <label for="antwoord">antwoord:</label>
   <input type="text" name="antwoord">
   <input type="hidden" name="vragen_id" value="{$row['vragen_id']}">
   <input type="submit" value="antwoord">
</form>
```

and catch the form data to insert it into the database AND do not forget to make the input safe before inserting.

```
if(isset($_POST) and !empty($_POST['vragen_id'])){
$antwoord = $_POST['antwoord'];

// add insert sql action here
insert into vragen (..fields..) values (..values..) where vragen_id = ........

// check results of the executed insert query

// head to the same page again and this you'll load the new answer
header('Location: http://www.example.com/antwoorden.php');
```

of course, if you only want to store it in the session. be my guest and do so.

Comment: Could you explain a little better on how to integrate this into my code because I can't seem to figure it out. Im quite new to using more complicated codes as I used to only really do easy things using very little php.